# expression "neck tingle"

Tags: expressions

I've seen the expression "neck tingle" used in the context of enjoying a good song. Is this a similar expression to "goose bumps"? If not, what would be the difference in use?

Comment: The main difference is if you say *"That song gives me goose bumps"*, most people will think you're speaking normal English. If you say *"That song gives me neck tingle"*, they'll still understand you (as meaning exactly the same thing), but they probably won't think you're speaking normal English.

Comment: I’m with @FumbleFingers: I’ve never heard *“neck tingle”* in my life. The only alternate for *“goose bumps”* I can think of is ***“frisson”*** (pronounced either `[fʁi(ˈ)sɔ̃]` or with greater assimilation, `[fɹɨˈsoʊn]`).

Comment: @tchrist, yahoo301503: But it's commonplace to say things like *"It made the [hairs on my neck tingle](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hairs+on+my+neck+tingle%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"*, so even if we've never heard "neck tingle" used as a standalone noun before, we'd all understand the reference. Whatever - if the question isn't "General Reference", it's "Too Localised".

Comment: This question [raises my hackles](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hackle).

Comment: This question could be improved by adding whatever you found when you tried to research the question before posting it. That's basic site etiquette. If you were reading [this blog post](http://imnotstalkingyou.com/2012/03/09/really-great-song-neck-tingle/), then the expression is defined in context, in the first paragraph. If you weren't ... it is anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the forming of a noun from a longer phrase, a relatively common practise in slang.

"It made (the hairs on the back of) my neck tingle" is a common phrase for something that is either exciting or frightful. This is sometimes expressed as an adjective or adverb phrase: neck-tingling or neck-tingly good, for example. Both of these are very much non-standard but might be used in sensationalist description, like music reviews.

From there, it's a fairly short step to "neck tingle" as a noun: 'It gave me a neck tingle', perhaps.

Another, much more established, example of this adaptation is 'bone-chilling' to describe something that chills the bones, either because it is scary or literally cold.